# Content of Facebook Open Graph urls

Tags: facebook-opengraph

I know Facebook open graph self hosted object uRLs should have their meta tags describing the object.
But I was wandering if they are supposed to have anything else at all?

i.e. Should they also provide user content? or are they just used for FB scraping?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are trying to do.Take a look at facebook Sharing Best Practices documents.

Comment: I have been reading through those docs for two days now. can you point to a more specific location where this issue is discussed?